# Struts Multiple Select Box Selections

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts

```
<html:select property="fields" multiple="true" style='width:200px;'>
    <html:options property='fieldsOptions'/>
</html:select>
```

fields is a String[] and fieldsOptions is an ArrayList I populate. When I do:

```
var selected = document.forms[0].fields;
```

It returns an array that has all of the options and not just the ones that have been selected. I just want to be able to look at the selected options. Remove them from fieldsOptions and move them into another selectedFields select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.forms[0].fields` is the `select` DOM element. You must iterate through its options and get the ones which are selected. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement for the documentation (in Mozilla) of the element. It shouldn't be much different in other browsers.

Note that cross-browser APIs like JQuery have cool shortcut methods to do this (See http://api.jquery.com/val/ )

Comment: Ok, thank you. You would think that fields would just contain the selected ones, I found out how to iterate through so thats what I needed

Comment: If fields would contain the selected values, and you were interested in not-selected ones, how would you do?

Comment: Well then I would look at fieldsOptions, or is there not a way to do that?